# Is $(t,\omega)\mapsto 1_{\{X\leq t\}}(w)$ jointly measurable?

Tags: probability-theory

Here is the motivation for my question:

I am given a sequence $(t_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ of random variables on some probability space $\Omega$ and I am supposed to show that
\begin{align}
N:\mathbb R\times \Omega&\to\mathbb R\\(t,\omega)&\mapsto \#\{k\in\mathbb N:\sum_{i=1}^kt_i(\omega)\leq t\}
\end{align}
is jointly measurable. I thought that maybe considering
$$T_i(\omega):=\sum_{i=1}^kt_i(\omega)$$and noticing that
$$N(t,\omega)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty1_{\{T_k\leq t\}}(\omega)$$does the trick. I guess that I can find some theorem that tells me that the infinite sum of non-negative functions is measurable, so I thought that the problem boils down to showing that
$$(t,\omega)\mapsto 1_{\{X\leq t\}}(w)$$is jointly measurable if $X$ is measurable. Considering the definition of measurability and the product $\sigma$-algebra doesn't seem very helpful, any hints? Or is my assumption wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that if $X$ is measurable, then the set $A=\{(t,\omega)\in\mathbb{R}\times\Omega:X(\omega)\leq t\}$ is measurable.  To prove this, just note that the function $Y:\mathbb{R}\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $Y(t,\omega)=(t,X(\omega))$ is measurable and $A=Y^{-1}(\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\leq x\})$ where $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\leq x\}$ is closed and hence measurable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Let $F:\mathbb R\times\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be the function that I want to be measurable. As far as I understand, you prove that $F^{-1}(\{1\})$ is measurable, right? To show that $F^{-1}(A)$ is measurable for each measurable $A$, I do a case distinction (I consider all possible truth values of $0\in A$ and $1\in A$) and I use the fact that $F^{-1}(\{0\}=(\mathbb R\times\Omega)\setminus F^{-1}(\{1\}$, i.e. $F^{-1}(\{0\}$ is measurable as well. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: That's correct.  By that argument, the characteristic function of a set is measurable iff that set is measurable.

Comment: Ah, so we are using the fact that$$\forall t:\forall\omega:1_{\{X\leq t\}}(\omega)=1_A(t,\omega).$$Thank you for the remark!